# Select Row if date Column is Between start and end date FMDB Request

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, fmdb

I am trying to write a SQL query for FMDB I have in my Objective C project.

My table consists of an id, num_of_items, startDate, endDate.

My query looks like this

```
FMResultSet * result = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM mytablename WHERE date BETWEEN ? AND ? ", lstartDate, lendDate];
```

however when this code runs I am getting the following error after the app crashes

```
[1210:2007096] DB Error: 1 "near "TRUNCATE": syntax error"
[1210:2007096] DB Query: TRUNCATE mytablename
```

The date column contains long values, I have checked both lstartDate and lendDate both of which are in the database table in that column.

The result I am after is that all values between and including start and end date are included in the output.

Comment: I would guess it is not the line you show us that is generating this error. Look for a query that contains the `TRUNCATE` sql command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting a single quote ' either side of the ?. Like this:

```
FMResultSet * result = [database executeQuery:@"SELECT * FROM mytablename WHERE date BETWEEN '?' AND '?' ", lstartDate, lendDate];
```

Comment: Mike, Just a follow up question that you may be able to help with, My query dose not return any values however both start and end date appear in the date column. why would it not be returning date?

Comment: I am a little confused why you have start and end dates in the table itself, surely you would only have a date in the table and then run queries on that date. The query you are performing is looking for a column called 'date' and returning rows where 'date' is between the specified dates. I didn't catch that the first time around as I only looked at your syntax.